# Android, Java: Android resource linking failed -\...\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:15: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

In my AndroidManifest.xml I wrote this code:

```xml
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              package="example.on.myapp12"
              tools:ignore="ExtraText">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        
        <application
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:allowBackup="true">
        </application>
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="myapp12">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </manifest>
```

After app run I saw:

`Android resource linking failed`
`C:\Users\miroslav\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp12\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:15: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.`
I really don't know what could be wrong...

Comment: Add activity inside the application tag

Comment: I tried but it does not work: https://imgur.com/a/H0BidEz

Comment: Does your `MainActivity` have the package declaration `example.on.myapp12`?

Comment: @david-wasser yes

Comment: Well, moving the `<activity>` declaration inside the `<application>` declaration should solve your problem. I'm confused why it doesn't. In your screenshot the `<activity` declaration is underlined in red and `.MainActivity` is also marked red. If you hover over these things with the mouse, do you get more information about why? Does the class `MainActivity` extend `Activity`?

Comment: Add activity name like com.example.appname.MainActvity. And make sure your activity class is extending Actvity or its subclass.

Comment: @DavidWasser There are two images in the link second is with problems after mouse hover.

Comment: So this indicates that there is no class named `example.on.myapp12.MainActivity` in your source tree. So maybe have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the activity tag in the application tag

**Add activity inside the application tag**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    package="example.on.myapp12"
                    tools:ignore="ExtraText">
                
                
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                
                    <application
                        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
                        android:allowBackup="true"
                        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
                        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                        android:supportsRtl="false"
                        android:theme="@style/Theme">
        
                     <activity
                        android:name=".MainActivity"
                        android:exported="true"
                        android:label="myapp12">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
        
                     </application>       
      
    </manifest>
```

Comment: I tried and there is this problem: https://imgur.com/a/IdcnQCv